# Facebook send button's pop up window on Tumblr

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

At the end of each post - I need to place the facebook social buttons (like and send). The problem I have - is on the very last post, ie the post at the bottom of the page, when a user clicks the facebook send button, the window opens below the button, to send the post link but it's cut off as the post is contained within a div and I don't want to pad it out just to make space for that window.

I was wondering does anyone know how to modify the buttons, such that the window appears above instead of below the button?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with the send button. Your you need to set the css property for whatever container it's in to

```
overflow:visible
```

That fixed the problem for me. Facebook suggests that here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/